# Event Kit calendar doesn't show up in iCal

Tags: ios, calendar, eventkit

I am creating a local calendar using Event Kit and saving the calendar.  When I go to Apples Calendar App and view my calendar it does not appear.  The weird thing is that it works on my iPhone 5, but not on my iPhone 6.  I receive no errors in the debugger. Does anyone have any idea above this?

Answer (score 2):

Check if your icloud is on. I just ran into the same problem too that local calendar won't show when icloud is on.